# check if input is between two int or float then display or not display content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, input

In javascript I need to check whiwh value user enter in an html input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="volume" class="form-control" name="voilume"></input>

<div id"button"></div>
```

Ineed to know if the input is between 0,5 and 8 (so I have int and float as you can understand).

So the value has to be **>= 0,5 and <= 8**

If value input if between 0,5 and 8 I have to display a button, else nothing to do. But I need to prevent if user change the value many times.

So if he enters 3 display a button in div id=button", if it changes for another value like 2 for example keep displaying the button, but if he changes value input for 100 I need to remove the button in div id="button".

for now I tried something like this in order to test if it works:

```
var input= $('#volume').val();
    if (input >= 0.5 && input <= 8) {
        $('#button').html('ok');
    } else {
      $('#button').empty();
    }
```

But it does not work.

Comment: 0,5   ??  you mean to say 0.5  ?

Comment: have you tried `parseFloat()`?

Comment: @Oxi sorry for the type `0,5`  I wrote my question too fast

Comment: @Oxi He is a french guy, we use comma as decimal separator here :)

Comment: What about providing MCVE replicating your issue?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit the *CSS Constraint Validation* here a little bit. It seems to me like a X/Y Problem. Actually, we could set our *min*, *max* and *step* values for this `<input>` element and then let the browser do the validation:

```
<input type="number" min="0.5" max="8" step="0.1" required id="volume" class="form-control" name="voilume">
```

Alongside this, we can make usage of the pseudo css selectors `:valid` and `:invalid` like so:

```
input:valid~div#button {
  display: block;
}

input:invalid~div#button {
  display: none;
}
```

This would have the effect, that if we enter a valid value in our input control, the button will be displayed. If not, the button disappears. Magic!

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4q1fjqwp/

Comment: Good one but what about browser support? Would it work on Safari? (required attribute / :valid pseudo class?!)

Comment: Pretty sure the css constraint API is well supported by now.

Comment: i see partial support for Safari but as i cannot currently test it, i'm not sure what it means...  http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation  Anyway, i like the use of CSS for layout purpose only ;)

Comment: @jAndy I test your code in IE8, it is not worked. How can I resolve that ?

Comment: definitely support for safari, the only thing I would be worried is IE (as usual). Can't test right now, but the API is actually pretty old. Even IE should have implemented this stuff by now.

Comment: @french_dev well, there are some shim libraries available, for instance: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html. So you can use that if you want to stick with all HTML5 shiny stuff. The other way around is to stick with validating with Javascript yourself (like other answers in this thread proposed to).
It looks like, IE is the only browser which does not support this great API.

Comment: @jAndy thank you for your advices. And by the way thank to all of yours for helping me with that questions. Happy coding

Comment: @jAndy another question: user could write a value `> 8`, the actually css with the `required` html attr and `max="8"` should be a problem for php validation, right ?

Comment: @french_dev He could, but there is no 100% way to avoid that on the client. Client can only be a helper and tool, but there must be a rock solid validation on the server in any case.

Answer (score 3):

.val() of an input field is a string, you have to convert it to a number in order to be able to compare it to numbers by >=, <=. You also had a typo: `id"button"`

```js
function go() {
    var input=parseFloat($('#volume').val(), 10);
    if (input >= 0.5 && input <= 8) {
        $('#button').html('ok');
    } else {
      $('#button').empty();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="volume" class="form-control" name="voilume"/>

<div id="button"></div>

<button onclick="go()">run</button>
```

Comment: @A.Wolff, I didn't know. However: `"012" < 013` => `false`

Comment: Ya because octal but same issue with your code anyway

Answer (score 1):

The problem may happen when input contain comma `,`
so `"0,5" >= 0.5` will return `false` and `parseFloat("0,5")` will return `0`.

You need replace `,` with `.`

Answer (score 0):

Something like below will work.

```
<input type="text" id="myTextField" onblur="change()"/>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="" />
```

JavaScript

```
function change() {
        var myTextbox = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
        var button = document.getElementById('byBtn');
        if (parseFloat(myTextbox) >= 0.5 && parseFloat(myTextbox) <= 8) {
            button.value = "OK";
        } else {
            button.value = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to parse string value  to integer. for that  use parseInt(). 
 it will parse string to integer.

replace this:

var input= $('#volume').val();

by

var inputval= parseInt($('#volume').val());

Comment: He needs float, so parseFloat not parseInt

Comment: @Raj No he doesn't have to parse it, it is already parsed while compared to number